# Is there such a thing as analog and digital compatible cmos or ccd sensors?

Tags: analog, cmos, camera, ccd

I'm way over my head with this one but I am trying to learn about cmos/ccd(preferred) sensors in order to build my own camera. Looking to get analog video from a sensor in a very small package size <7mm.

The sensors I've come across all list digital specifications but from my understanding imaging sensors are inherently analog.

For example this is a cheap inexpensive sensor I've found.

https://www.arrow.com/en/products/ov05695-ga4a-1b/omnivision-technologies

Do I only need an analog compatible video driver?

Answer (score 0):

This chip as a 10 Bit ADC (analog to digital converter) on board and gives you a digital output stream via a MIPI serial output interface. It is controlled via a two-wire serial bus control (SCCB).

See the [datasheet](https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/fcbd4d8ddbd794eb12ed5fdd4f27402cf0cd583c/79804335836446download_document.phptypesensorsensorid202.phptypesensorsensorid2.pdf) on page 2:
[image]

So you will need a microcontroller to configure the CCD and to read the data stream.